# Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase messgessing sdk for push-notification. Here am not using androidx plugin. When am build its throw some error.

**My gradle...**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.xxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
//    packagingOptions {
//        pickFirst 'META-INF/*'
//        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
//    }
android.packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/*'
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
}
}
configurations.all { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }
dependencies {
ext {
    support_library_version = '28.0.0'
}
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Error is...**

```
Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver
```

once i remove the firebase sdk build is working fine. I search many solutions but still not working please anyone give me a solution.

Advance thanks...